# Sage graph plots are of random size and sometimes way too small

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sage

I run **jupyter** with **sage**: `sage -n jupyter` and plot graph like this:

```
from sage.graphs.graph_plot import GraphPlot

g = DiGraph({1:[6],2:[4],3:[5],4:[2],5:[3],6:[1]})
GP = g.graphplot( vertex_size=1000 )
GP.show()
```

but graphs (especially labels) appear way too small sometimes:

[image]

When I hit `Ctrl+Enter` multiple times (which causes redraw) it randomizes to desirable results:

[image]

Is it something to do with disconnected graphs?

P.S. Also, is there a way to merge bidirectional edges of directional graphs into single lines?